# Zooming and UIWebView

Tags: ios, pdf, uiwebview

I am having a problem with UIWebView. My application displays pdfs from local memory and displays them in a webView in fullscreen mode. By default, when the page loads, the content is apparently set to fit horizontally, which cuts off some of the bottom of the pdf. I would like it to initially show up vertically fit and horizontally centered. I have looked for an answer to this question for quit some time and can't seem to find anything.

Any ideas?

(Please do not suggest `scalesPageToFit`. Although it fixes many beginning problems, this is not one of them.)

Comment: I should clarify that this is really two questions: 1) How can I set the correct initial zoomFactor? and 2) how can I center the webView?

Comment: Is the pdf one page or multiple pages?

Comment: The way I am doing it now is a series of 1 page pdf files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uiWebView.scrollView property has the ability to set zoom and also manage display of content

[UIScollView class ref](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html)

Comment: Thanks. I set the content size and things worked out fairly well.